# AS3 Using a object as collision detection

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection

I'v been thinking and I want to know if this is a efficient way to make a game collision.

I am trying to make a game like Double Dragon(NES). I'm trying to copy the mechanic of moving up and down on a 2D screen but when you go back you go behind it.

But the mechanic I'm having trouble with is I want the feet to collide with an object but I'm not sure if hitTestPoint will do it so I want to use a object to be the collision detector.

The Player Collider will be attached to the feet, but I don't know how to keep the Collider on the feet of another object. I'v done it but when I do it, it is very laggy and I want to know how you guys would handle this.

---

Over all what I'm trying to say is. There are 2 objects, 1 of them is the player sprite and the other is the collision detector (which is also a object). I would like to know if that would be ok to use as a collision detector or is there a more efficient way of doing it.

---

Comment: IIRC NES resources were pretty scarce, so collisions were emulated as rectangle intersections, each char had a rectangle of feet, designating Z-depth, shifting upwards and downwards, a rectangle of body, designating XY-size, and rectangle(s) of attacks, and hit check was first feet vs feet then attack vs body, if both were true, process hit. You might create the same mechanics for your game.

Comment: You may adjust the pivot of each character so as to set the origin at the bottom center of the corresponding sprite. Then you just have to re-order your objects on stage according to their Y-coordinates.